# posting data to php via curl . jsondata.php is not giving json output

Tags: php, php-curl

```
**jsondata.php  not giving json-formatted o/p. **
    **index.php**
    <?php 
        $curl=curl_init();
        $var=3;
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/v/practice/curl/c3/jsondata.php");

        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"myVar=".$var);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $response=curl_exec($curl);
        $data=json_decode($response);
        //print_r($data);
        for ($a=0; $a < count($data); $a++) { 
            echo $data[$a]->id." ";
            echo $data[$a]->username." ";
            echo $data[$a]->password." ";
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    ?>
    ----------------------
    **jsondata.php** 
    <?php 
        $myVar=$_POST["myVar"];
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practicedb");
        $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from ex1 where id=".$myVar);
        $data=array();
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    ?>
```

> *Notice: Undefined index: myVar in C:\xampp\htdocs\v\practice\curl\c3\jsondata.php on line 2
>       Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\v\practice\curl\c3\jsondata.php on line 6
>       []*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple things-

Pass an array that you json encode for "myVar" so

```
$data = array('myVar' => $myVar);
```

and in your curl request:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

and add this option:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
```

Passing the variable where your jsondata.php script can read it should help with your mysql error - hard to say what else might be a problem until you're successfully passing all parts of the query to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You main problem is that your cURL request is sending a `GET` request instead of a `POST` request. You have to set the `CURLOPT_POST` setting to make it a `POST` request. After that the expression `$_POST["myVar"]` will get you the value you want.

Additionally you should use prepared statements for SQL queries which depend on variables. And you should check for SQL errors, don't assume everything is working all the time.